# how to install ruby 3.0.0 in macOS Catalina

Tags: ruby

Now I am using this command to install ruby 3.0.0 in macOS Catalina:

```
rvm get stable 

rvm install ruby-3.0.0
```

shows this error:

```
    $ rvm install ruby-3.0.0
    Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
    No binary rubies available for: osx/10.15/x86_64/ruby-3.0.0.
    Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
    Checking requirements for osx.
    Installing requirements for osx.
    Updating system - please wait
    Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions at
    
        https://docs.brew.sh/Common-Issues
    
    and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
    Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-3.0.0',
    please read /Users/dolphin/.rvm/log/1615433437_ruby-3.0.0/update_system.log
    Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
    (base)
```

Is it possible to install ruby using rvm in macOS Catalina 10.15.7? what should I do to make it work? where should I find the binary? This is my rvm info:

```
    $ rvm -v
    rvm 1.29.12 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
    (base)
```

and then I check the log:

```
$ tail -f /Users/dolphin/.rvm/log/1615433437_ruby-3.0.0/update_system.log
+rvm_error:2> rvm_pretty_print stderr
+rvm_pretty_print:2> case auto (0|no)
+rvm_pretty_print:2> case auto (1|auto)
+rvm_pretty_print:8> case xterm-256color (dumb|unknown)
+rvm_pretty_print:12> case stderr (stdout)
+rvm_pretty_print:12> case stderr (stderr)
+rvm_pretty_print:14> [[ -t 2 ]]
+rvm_pretty_print:14> return 1
+rvm_error:4> printf %b $'Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions at\n\n    https://docs.brew.sh/Common-Issues\n\nand make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\\n'
+requirements_osx_brew_update_system:27> return 1
wqq^C
(base)
```

and runs `brew update` command:

```
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
(base)
```

seems the rvm update failed but successed in command line env.

Comment: This is not primarily an issue regarding the installation of Ruby or rvm. The error message tells that `bundle update` failed. And that you should read `/Users/dolphin/.rvm/log/1615433437_ruby-3.0.0/update_system.log`. Probably that logfile explains what went wrong and how to fix it. Can you please copy and paste the content of that logfile into your question?

Comment: I pasted the log but the error tips seems conflict. @spickermann

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the XCode command line tools installed? Usually, you can do that by running `xcode-select --install` from the CLI

Comment: Check `brew doctor` as well.